# Why do getCell() writes on the wrong sheet, but only in a for loop?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array consisting of a list of Dates, named q. I want to input it into the E column, on a specific sheet inside the spreadsheet. When using a for loop to input the values for q into the cells of the target column, it works, but inputs them on an unrelated sheet, which isn't even referenced in that script.

I've logged the array, it's populated correctly. It's 2-dimensionnal. 
I've colored each relevant step of the Init to make sure my variables were targetting the good sheet. They are. They're mistargeting only when in the for loop.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CSV Import') // CSV input sheet
var rangeA = sheet.getRange('A2:A999'); // Column 1
var rangeB = sheet.getRange('B2:B999'); // Column 2
var rangeC = sheet.getRange('C2:C999'); // Column 3
var rangeD = sheet.getRange('D2:D999'); // Column 4
var rangeE = sheet.getRange('E2:E999'); // Column 5
// rangeE.getCell(1,1).setBackgroundColor("#99CC00"); works
```

```
for ( a = 0; a < q.length; a++) {

    var cellE = rangeE.getCell(a + 1,1);
//  cellE.setBackgroundColor("#99CC00"); doesn't work
    var valueToSet = q[a];
    cellE.setValue(valueToSet);
  }
```

Expected results : The for loop colors the E column on the CSV Import sheet, and populates it with the data from q.

Actual results : The for loop colors the E column on another unrelated sheet on the same spreadsheet, and populates it with the data from q.

Comment: **Where** is `rangeE` defined, in relation to the loop? And why why why why why would you ever write in a loop, when you can simply write everything all at once? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations

Comment: Well, you made me realize where my mistake was. ```rangeE``` was defined outside of the loop, which javascript apparently doesn't like much. At least, redifining it inside solved everything, and allowed me to get rid of the loop altogether, using a much simpler function.

As to why I wrote in a loop, the answer is simple : I'm not a developer and never learned js (or any other language for that matter). That's the only way I knew, but I learned something new and that's nice ! Thanks !